# Each ESI request makes the same database queries

Tags: php, symfony, caching

I am using Symfony 2.4. As I started using the HTTP cache in combination with some ESI render calls my web profiler showed me that I now have duplicate DB queries. For instance the user is fetched in the master request but also in the ESI subrequest. I am using the Symfony2 standard reverse proxy and not Varnish. The user query is not done manually but because the session gets reloaded. Is there a way to avoid this behavior?